# Flutter: in-app purchase credit card tests

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

How can I test my subscription/products without paying for real?

I'm using the official package:
https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Android, you need to sign into the play console and go to `settings` > `developer account` > `account details` > `license testing` and add the email you use on your test device.
While making a payment, you should see the `test card` as the method of payment which will always process successfully without actually charging any money.

 Since this is a test purchase, if left unacknowledged, it should be nullified after 5 minutes and you can test again and again.

Comment: The path of the Google Play Console page is now `Setup` > `License testing`